# Debug C++ in Xcode

Tags: c++, xcode

With my all exceptions breakpoint set my execution pauses on the following line at launch in main.m, I can continue and the program seems to execute fine.

```
    return UIApplicationMain(argc, argv, nil, NSStringFromClass([AppDelegate class]));
```

[image]

Based on everything I have read this is a C++ error.  I have added he following debugger command po $arg1 but this only give me a number in the debugger console.  This is not very helpful for figuring out what is wrong.

105827995320056

Any suggestion would be greatly appreciated.

BTW I have already search for custom fonts that have caused others the same issue.

Comment: Yes, `__cxa_throw` is the runtime implementation of the `throw` keyword in C++. However, if some other part of the library code has a `catch` and handles the exception, this is not a problem.

Comment: @BoPersson Thanks for commenting but I am really not sure what you are trying to tell me here.

Comment: I'm trying to say that this *is* a C++ exception being thrown, but that in itself is not an indication of a problem. An exception does not have to be an error, but could be a condition that is unexpected but still handled by the program.

Comment: @BoPersson I see thankyou!